# Allow user to connect their database to django app

Tags: django, database, django-models, database-connection

I am developing an app in which user stores their data. I want to add option to allow user to connect their database (on their server) to the django project so that they can store their sensitive information. Eg:-
Data stored on my app database -> Name, Username, Email
Data stored on user database -> Phone, Bank Details etc.

I cannot configure user database credentials in settings.py as it will be dynamic and different for different users.

So, how do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use sqlalchemy to solve the problem. I also integrated batch script and django views to create tables. If any one has the same issue, i can share the code.

Here is the quick link of sqlalchemy: https://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can't have different databases for different users. The database is for the site.

In terms of security, people have access to the data you allow them to in the database. So if security is important, just structure the data in such a way that people can store what they need & only access what they're supposed to.

It sounds to me like you need to think about your database design to accomplish what people need, and then ensure the project keeps data restricted to the correct people.

Comment: Actually, i am working with the multiple government organisations. So as per their policies, their data cannot be stored on other than their database. Is their any way to call the database from within the views and passing server credentials

Comment: You'll have to give each of them a version of the application each.

Comment: No, python isn't a compiled language, but you shouldn't need to. Clients don't need the source code, just access to the system.